# black screen with blinking cursor

Tags: windows-7, boot

I wanted to downgrade a computer from Windows 8 to Windows 7. When I tried to install using Windows 7 installation disk on boot, and I tried to install on a partition, I would get

```
windows cannot be installed on this disk. 
The selected disk is of the GPT partition style.
```

So, based on a tutorial I read online, I booted from the Gparted disk I created, and used Gparted to delete all partitions on the hard drive. Under “Device” I chose Create Partition Table to make a new partition table. I created a NTFS partition.

The instructions then say

```
Then boot from the Windows install disk and install Windows.
```

However, when I try to boot from DVD disk, I just get a black screen with a blinking cursor (if I try to boot from hard drive, it says "no boot device available"). So how can I fix this blinking cursor issue so I could boot from the disk and install Windows 7?

Comment: I just checked my bios and the dvd was not in first boot order. When I set that first, it now does boot from dvd.

Comment: So are you able to install Win7 now? If not, try turning off Secure Boot from the BIOS/UEFI Settings.